# How to find the shortest path between opposite vertices of a cube, traveling on its surface?

Tags: geometry

I am stuck with the following problem that says:

> Let $A,B$ be the ends of the longest diagonal of the unit cube . The length of 
>   the shortest path from $A$ to $B$ along the surface is :

1. $\sqrt{3}\,\,$  2.$\,\,1+\sqrt{2}\,\,$  3.$\,\,\sqrt{5}\,\,$ 4.$\,\,3$

My Try: [image]

So, the length of the longest diagonal $AB=\sqrt{3}$. If I reach from $A$ to $B$ along the surface line $AC+CD+BD$, then it gives $3$ units. But the answer is given to be option 3.

Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Consider the cube as a 6-sided cardboard box made by folding a flat T-shaped piece of cardboard made of 6 squares sharing some common edges. Unfold the box, draw a straight line on it from A to B. Re-fold. It did not ask for a path that stays on the edges of the cube.

Comment: Make that an answer!

Comment: Lust flatten the side that includes BCD. You get a right angle triangle with sides 2 and 1. The hypotenuse is $\sqrt{5}$. Draw the line connecting A and flatten B. Return the side containing BCD to its original position. It is exactly what user254665 means.

Comment: The problem with learners solution is that he isn't taking a path along the surface. Unfolding the net of the cube doesn't change lengths so the answer is $\sqrt{2^2+1} = \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Got it..

Answer (score 4):

[image: ShortestPathUnitCube]

The path goes through the middle point of common opposite side considering two squares only.

Answer (score 0):

**You are right, but for the wrong question.** You answered the question "what is the shortest path between A and B". However, the question, as written, includes "along the surface" - this requires following e.g. user254665's suggestion.

If we can't go through the interior of the cube, the 3D structure is just cognitive noise and we map this surface to a 2D embedding by e.g. unfolding the box, leaving the edge CD in tact. This leaves us with a rectangle of length 2 and width 1, A and B on opposite corners, and you can calculate the length.